# Please explain to me how a setter work inside a class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, this, getter-setter, setter

**The Goal**: Use the class keyword to create a Thermostat class. The constructor accepts a Fahrenheit temperature. In the class, create a getter to obtain the temperature in Celsius and a setter to set the temperature in Celsius.

Here's my code so far:

```
class Thermostat {
  constructor(fahrenheit){
    this.fahrenheit = fahrenheit;
  }

  get temperature(){
    const inCelcius = 5/9 * (this.fahrenheit - 32) ;
    return inCelcius;

  }

  set temperature (temperatureInCelcius){
    this.fahrenheit = temperatureInCelcius;
  }

}

const thermos = new Thermostat(76); // Setting in Fahrenheit scale
let temp = thermos.temperature; // should show 24.44 in Celsius
console.log(temp);
thermos.temperature = 26;
temp = thermos.temperature; // should show 26 in Celsius but right now showing -3.333
console.log(temp);
```

I know the correct solution is to change `this.fahrenheit = temperatureInCelcius;` into `this.fahrenheit = (celsius * 9.0) / 5 + 32;`

But I don’t understand why. I've been told that my code is missing a conversion.

My questions are:

1. Why is there a need to convert Fahrenheit into celsius?
2. What exactly happens in this line? `thermos.temperature = 26;` My understanding is that when the compiler sees that line, it invokes this line inside the constructor

```
set temperature (temperatureInCelcius){
    this.fahrenheit = temperatureInCelcius;
  }
```

and then put 26 into the argument `(temperatureInCelcius)`, then set the property value of `this.fahrenheit` to 26.

Just want some explanation cause it feels like I am missing something. Would greatly appreciate your help! <3

Comment: You're converting farenheit -> celsius when reading, so you need to convert celsius -> farenheit when writing. `2: My understanding is that` Thats not a constructor, otherwise thats corrent. `I know the correct solution is to change this.fahrenheit = temperatureInCelcius;` Yeah, because you're storing __celsius__ in your variable supposed to hold a __farenheit__ value.

Comment: `this.fahrenheit = temperatureInCelcius` shows a poor choice in variable names. It implies that the incoming temperature (in world units) is converted at this point to freedom units - which isn't the case

Comment: @tkausl Thank you so much for your explanation. Can you tell me more about the reading and writing part?

Comment: I thought the setter just delete the current value of this.fahrenheit and overwrites it with 26? Is that not the case?

Comment: correct ... so now your Fahrenheit value is the number `26` - and when you `get` the `temperature` it converts 26 Fahrenheit into the corresponding Celcius

Comment: you need to convert the incoming `celcius`  value to `fahrenheit`  before you store it in `this.fahrenheit`

Comment: Not sure how I helped. I guess you knew you had to do it, you say so in the question, you needed to know why? Somehow my comment made something click :p

Comment: @bravo I didn't take into account the fact that when you get the temperature after setting it, it goes through a conversion again. When you said, "when you get the temperature it converts 26 Fahrenheit into the corresponding Celcius" was when it clicked for me! :D You'd made a great teacher, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `temp = thermos.temperature;`, `get temperature()` is called and for `thermos.temperature = 26;` `set temperature()` is called.

```
// thermos.temperature = 76
const thermos = new Thermostat(76);

// this calls get temperature() and return 24.44
// 5/9 * (76 - 32) = 24.44
let temp = thermos.temperature;

console.log(temp); // 24.44

// this calls set temperature() and sets thermos.temperature = 26
thermos.temperature = 26;

// this calls get temperature() and return -3.333
// 5/9 * (26 - 32) = -3.333
temp = thermos.temperature;

console.log(temp); // -3.33
```